# mysql транзакции. Как проверить, есть ли у клиента деньги на покупку товара?

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день. 
У меня есть пример
Клиент А имеет на балансе 50 EUR и хочет купить товар за 60 UER.

Примеры таблицы Users

```
id  name  amount
1   Ivan  50.00
```

Пример таблицы Products

```
id name price
1  tv   60.00
```

я использую php, если вы можете, помогите с этим примером)

Answer (score 1):

```
begin;
update users set balance = balance - :amount 
    where balance >= amount and id=:user_id;
```

Если от последнего запроса affected_rows = 1, то регистрируем заказ, делаем что там ещё надо в базе, потом делаем `commit`.

Если `affected_rows` был 0 - значит или клиента такого нет или у него не достаточно денег на балансе. Делаем `rollback` и говорим клиенту, что денег нет.

Можно сделать `select ... for update` и посчитать баланс на клиенте, затем сделать `update` но зачем? Тем более на php расчёт скорей всего вы сделаете в float с соответствующими ошибками, а СУБД нормально посчитает свой numeric.